# Python: How do I fill an array with a range of numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fill

So I have an array of 100 elements:

```
a = np.empty(100)
```

How do I fill it with a range of numbers? I want something like this:

```
b = a.fill(np.arange(1, 4, 0.25))
```

So I want it to keep filling `a` with that values of that range on and on until it reaches the size of it

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`np.put`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) places values from `b` into `a` at the target indices, `ind`. If `v` is shorter than `ind`, its values are repeated as necessary:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.empty(100)
b = np.arange(1, 4, 0.25)
ind = np.arange(len(a))
np.put(a, ind, b)
print(a)
```

yields

```
[ 1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.    2.25  2.5   2.75  3.    3.25  3.5   3.75
  1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.    2.25  2.5   2.75  3.    3.25  3.5   3.75
  1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.    2.25  2.5   2.75  3.    3.25  3.5   3.75
  1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.    2.25  2.5   2.75  3.    3.25  3.5   3.75
  1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.    2.25  2.5   2.75  3.    3.25  3.5   3.75
  1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.    2.25  2.5   2.75  3.    3.25  3.5   3.75
  1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.    2.25  2.5   2.75  3.    3.25  3.5   3.75
  1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.    2.25  2.5   2.75  3.    3.25  3.5   3.75
  1.    1.25  1.5   1.75]
```

Answer (score 4):

updating solution to fit description

```
a = np.empty(100)
filler = np.arange(1,4,0.25)
index = np.arange(a.size)
np.put(a,index,filler)
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I need the size of the array to be fixed, in that case it works because it meets 100 elements. But if we put instead of 0.25 steps of 5; we end up with an array of 5 elements. What I need in this case is the array to keep recording the elements until it reaches its size

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. Array size, step size and starting value are all fixed, right ?

Comment: Yes I need to have 100 elements and they have to be within a certain range

Comment: so the step does not matter ? if the range is 1 to 5, step should be calculated accordingly so that it fills up 100 elements ?

Comment: If the range is let's say (1,6,2) I need the array to have 100 elements of [1,3,5,1,3,5....3]

Comment: got it. give me a min

Answer (score 2):

Such a simple feat can be achieved in plain python, too

```
>>> size = 100
>>> b = [v/4 for v in range(4,16)]
>>> a = (b * (size // len(b) + 1))[:size]
>>> a
[1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3.0, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 
 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3.0, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 
 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3.0, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 
 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3.0, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 
 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3.0, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 
 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3.0, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 
 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3.0, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 
 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3.0, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 
 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75]
```

with these exact conditions it's about 3 times faster than `numpy`.